# Reordering records by category in October CMS?

Tags: octobercms

So far I've reordered my plugin's records according to the [October documentation](https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/reorder), but now I need to take it a step further.
Let's say I have products which have multiple categories:

```
apple  -> (fruits, desserts)    
banana -> (fruits, desserts)
cherry -> (fruits, desserts)
```

Now the idea is to reorder the products according to each category:

```
fruits:
1 - apple
2 - banana
3 - cherry

desserts:
1 - cherry
2 - apple
3 - banana
```

I guess I need an extra pivot table `reorder_category_product` looking something like this:

```
category_id | product_id | sort_order 
      1            1            1
      1            2            2
      1            3            3
      2            3            1
      2            1            2
      2            2            3
```

But how can achieve that ?
Is there any example or October's plugin to put me on the right track ?

Comment: I know how to do it directly by QueryBuilder (`Db::table` and `join`) but not by model classes

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this post

https://octobercms.com/forum/post/reordering-items-in-a-relation

with its github https://github.com/scottbedard/draganddrop.

Or Mall plugin has implemented what you are looking for, take a look at how you can reorder only products of a certain category

https://octobercms.com/plugin/offline-mall

Hope this helps!

Comment: IMHO it's not an answer

Comment: Well, this is the question. "Is there any example or October's plugin to put me on the right track?". Anyway, feel free to think differently. Cheers